# (Extracting structure failed: Build status: Error) Unable to import plugin to scala in plugins.sbt file

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I'm trying to use sbt-native-packager to make Docker Image of scala project. I have to add sbt-native-packager plugin. For that, I've created "plugins.sbt" file in book_system_task/project/plugins.sbt (where book_system_task is my application name).

plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.9.4")
```

But on loading sbt changes, it gives following error:

```
Extracting structure failed: Build status: Error
```

I'm currently using, scala-version: 2.13.1, sbt-version:1.2.8.

Answer (score 1):

The error is

```
[error] sbt.internal.IncompatiblePluginsException: Binary incompatibility in plugins detected.
...
[error] Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sbt.package$.singleFileJsonFormatter()Lsjsonnew/JsonFormat;
```

Method `sbt.package$.singleFileJsonFormatter()` appeared in sbt 1.3.0

https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/v1.3.0/sbt/src/main/scala/package.scala#L48

https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/v1.2.8/sbt/src/main/scala/package.scala

```
implicit val singleFileJsonFormatter: JsonFormat[File] = FileStamp.Formats.fileJsonFormatter
```

So sbt-native-packager 1.9.4 seems to be binary incompatible with sbt 1.2.8-

Either upgrade sbt to 1.3.0+ in `project/build.properties` (current sbt is 1.8.2) or downgrade sbt-native-packager as you did in your next question [Unable to make docker image using sbt-native-packager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76012663/unable-to-make-docker-image-using-sbt-native-packager)