# Unable to make docker image using sbt-native-packager

Tags: docker, scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I'm learning to make docker image of scala application using sbt-native-packager. My application contains akka-http and running fine on localhost:8080 **(scala-version: 2.13.1, sbt-version: 1.2.8)**. Now for making docker image. First I make 'plugins.sbt'.

**projects/plugins.sbt:**

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.7.2")
```

Then I enable plugins in 'build.sbt'.

**build.sbt:**

```
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.1"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "book_system_task"
  )

enablePlugins(
  JavaAppPackaging,
  DockerPlugin
)
Compile / mainClass := Some("server.Server")
Docker / packageName := "testImage/book-system-task"
    
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.6.0",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.7.0",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % "10.5.0",
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.4.4",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-spray-json" % "10.5.0",
  "com.google.inject" % "guice" % "5.1.0",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream-testkit" % "2.7.0",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-testkit" % "10.5.0",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.11",
  "com.outworkers" %% "phantom-dsl" % "2.59.0"
)
```

Now I have to run 'sbt docker:publishLocal' (I'm confused where to run this command in intellij idea), I run this command(docker:publishLocal) in sbt-shell.

**Output after running 'docker:publishLocal' in sbt-shell:**

```
docker:publishLocal
[info] Packaging /home/zaryab/Downloads/book_system_task/target/scala-2.13/book_system_task_2.13-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar ...
[info] Wrote /home/zaryab/Downloads/book_system_task/target/scala-2.13/book_system_task_2.13-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Updating ...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies; run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings.
[info] Main Scala API documentation to /home/zaryab/Downloads/book_system_task/target/scala-2.13/api...
[info] Compiling 30 Scala sources to /home/zaryab/Downloads/book_system_task/target/scala-2.13/classes ...
model contains 60 documentable templates
[info] Main Scala API documentation successful.
[info] Packaging /home/zaryab/Downloads/book_system_task/target/scala-2.13/book_system_task_2.13-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Done compiling.
[info] Packaging /home/zaryab/Downloads/book_system_task/target/scala-2.13/book_system_task_2.13-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] :: delivering :: book_system_task#book_system_task_2.13;0.1.0-SNAPSHOT :: 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT :: integration :: Fri Apr 14 11:59:55 PKT 2023
[info]  delivering ivy file to /home/zaryab/Downloads/book_system_task/target/scala-2.13/ivy-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.xml
[info]  published book_system_task_2.13 to /home/zaryab/.ivy2/local/book_system_task/book_system_task_2.13/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/poms/book_system_task_2.13.pom
[info]  published book_system_task_2.13 to /home/zaryab/.ivy2/local/book_system_task/book_system_task_2.13/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/jars/book_system_task_2.13.jar
[info]  published book_system_task_2.13 to /home/zaryab/.ivy2/local/book_system_task/book_system_task_2.13/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/srcs/book_system_task_2.13-sources.jar
[info]  published book_system_task_2.13 to /home/zaryab/.ivy2/local/book_system_task/book_system_task_2.13/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/docs/book_system_task_2.13-javadoc.jar
[info]  published ivy to /home/zaryab/.ivy2/local/book_system_task/book_system_task_2.13/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[success] Total time: 9 s
```

But still after this, I'm not able to see where Dockerfile is created. Or Docker Image/File is created or not.

Comment: execute: docker images

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the [docs of sbt-native-packager](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html#tasks), you have 4 tasks that you can execute.

- `docker:publishLocal`: will build the image and publish in your local docker server. Based on your output, looks like you have already installed it. Just running `docker images` from the terminal you should be able to see an image with the name `testImage/book-system-task`.

If you want to generate a Dockerfile, you should use the task `docker:stage`. The output of executing that task will tell you where the file is located