# sbt scoverage plugin error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sbt.package$.singleFileJsonFormatter()Lsjsonnew/JsonFormat;

Tags: scala, sbt, scoverage

i am trying to use [scoverage](https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage) for code coverage in my plugins.sbt i have added

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scoverage" % "sbt-scoverage" % "2.0.9")
```

here is my build.sbt

```
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.1"
coverageEnabled := true
```

here is build.properties file

```
sbt.version = 1.2.8
```

upon building project, i am getting the following exception

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sbt.package$.singleFileJsonFormatter()Lsjsonnew/JsonFormat;
[error]     at scoverage.ScoverageKeys$.coverageSourceRoot$lzycompute(ScoverageKeys.scala:22)
[error]     at scoverage.ScoverageKeys$.coverageSourceRoot(ScoverageKeys.scala:22)
[error]     at scoverage.ScoverageSbtPlugin$.coverageReport0$lzycompute(ScoverageSbtPlugin.scala:215)
[error]     at scoverage.ScoverageSbtPlugin$.coverageReport0(ScoverageSbtPlugin.scala:203)
[error]     at scoverage.ScoverageSbtPlugin$.projectSettings(ScoverageSbtPlugin.scala:68)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$resolveProject$3(Load.scala:1062)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:240)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:388)
```

i have tried to downgrade to the version
2.0.5 and 2.0.4 as given [here](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.scoverage/sbt-scoverage/2.0.4/versions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the version of sbt you are using. Here you have some links for reference

- [Unable to import plugin to scala in plugins.sbt file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76096669/7214091)

> Method sbt.package$.singleFileJsonFormatter() appeared in sbt 1.3.0
>
> So sbt-native-packager 1.9.4 seems to be binary incompatible with sbt 1.2.8-
>
> Either upgrade sbt to 1.3.0+ in project/build.properties (current sbt is 1.8.2) or downgrade sbt-native-packager as you did in your next question [Unable to make docker image using sbt-native-packager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76012663/unable-to-make-docker-image-using-sbt-native-packager)

- [Broken compatibility with SBT 1.2.8](https://github.com/lightbend/mima/issues/417)
- [sbt plugin does not work with 1.2.8 if plugin build with 1.3.0](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/5049)

Comment: thanks i have updated sbt version to latest and scoverage to 2.0.5